# understanding the Earth Mover’s Distance (EMD) from the MATLAB

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I found difficulty in understanding the Earth Mover’s Distance (EMD) from the MATLAB implementation. The method is actually implemented in this [paper](https://talhassner.github.io/home/projects/cnn_emotions/LeviHassner_ICMI15.pdf).
Anyone help me to where EMD is implemented in this code.

```
cyclic_dist_matrix=zeros(256,256);
for ix=0:255
    ix_bin_vec = [0,de2bi(ix,8)];
    for jx=0:255
        jx_bin_vec = [0,de2bi(jx,8)];
        dist1=pdist2(ix_bin_vec,jx_bin_vec,'emd');
        dist2=pdist2(wrev(ix_bin_vec),jx_bin_vec,'emd');
        dist3=pdist2(ix_bin_vec,wrev(jx_bin_vec),'emd');
        cyclic_dist_matrix(ix+1,jx+1) = min([dist1,dist2,dist3]);
    end
end

%mds
Y=mdscale(cyclic_dist_matrix,3);
Y2=Y + abs(min(Y(:)));
Y2 = Y2 * (255/max(Y2(:)));
cyclic_map=uint8(Y2);
```

Comment: What the paper describes is not a true EMD, but just approximation. Also try avoiding for loops in matlab.

Answer (score 1):

```
dist1=pdist2(ix_bin_vec,jx_bin_vec,'emd');
```

The MATLAB function `pdist2(X,Y, metric)` calculates the distance between vectors X and Y using the metric in the third argument. Specifying `'emd'` as the metric tells MATLAB to use the earth movers distance metric.

Comment: emd as argument does not work for me. 

Error using pdist2 (line 158)
"Unrecognized 'DISTANCE' argument: emd."

Comment: I have some randomly generated 2d data, now with those, I drew 3d histogram and using a surface command, I approximated a probability density surfaces i.e distribution. If I have such two different probability distribution out of 3d histogram, how can I calculate and between them?